# Editor from EditorJS not showing up. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I want to use EditorJS in my project. So I have created an HTML file after reading the documentation. Here is the file called *index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="editorjs"></div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>
    <script>
        import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs'
        const editor = new EditorJS('editorjs')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After opening the file into the browser, EditorJS is not showing up and this message is printed in the console- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The script isn't a type module, use:

```html
<script type="module">
```

Comment: I have used `<script type="module"></script>`. Now the error says- `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@editorjs/editorjs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="editorjs"></div>
  <script>
    const editor = new EditorJS({
      autofocus: true
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When you add a script tag in your HTML file, you don't need to import the library again you can just start using it!

Comment: EditorJS is showing up now. But I can't use tools such as Header, List etc. Do you have any solution?

Comment: It highly depends upon ur use case I would recommend watching a tutorial on how to use editorJS